# Linking object from custom library

Tags: c#, dll, xamarin.android, monodevelop, xamarin-studio

I have this feeling that this should be quite simple, but I might be missing something simple that I can't find.

I have this personal lib I created in MonoDevelop. Nothing too fancy:

```
namespace GMapsLib
{
    public class MapMaker : FragmentActivity
    {
        public static bool tmpVar;
        public MapMaker(int ressId){
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

And here's what I want to do:

```
using GMapsLib;

namespace GMapsApp
{
    public class Activity1 : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle){
            ...
            GMapsLib.MapMaker.tmpVar = true;
            MapMaker myMap = new MapMaker(Resource.Id.FLay_mapContainer);
        }
    }
}
```

That MapMaker line results in the following error: The type or namespace name 'MapMaker' could not be found. For the record, the `GMapsLib.MapMaker.tmpVar = true;` line prompts the following: The type or namespace name 'MapMaker' does not exist in the namespace 'GMapsLib'.

I have linked GMapsLib in the references folder of my solution trough the Mono IDE, cleaned and rebuild. Even the autocomplete for the GMapsLib elements works, so I'm out of ideas as to what I'm missing.

Any ideas?

**Some notes:**

I'm working with Xamarin Studio on a Mac and this is testing for an android app

Comment: Do you have the class library project that has the `GMapsLib` namespace with the target framework as `.Net Framework 4.0 Client Profile`. If so, please change it to `.Net Framework 4.0` and then try building

Comment: Yeah I found the SO question related to the .NET profiles, but I'm working with Mono and not VS. I can't find any option related to a .NET profile in the project options for the GMapsLib (nor in the solution options). I should note that this is Android and Xamarin related (I'll add it to the question). But both the lib and the application have the same target framework